# How can I update service in Angulars' @Input

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this situation:

```
<app-component-test [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-component-test>
```

`dataSource` is a service inited in component's constructor. Now I change this service property by:

```
this.dataSource.list = [1, 2, 3];
```

but `app-component-test` doesn't have any changes. I need to have in component this service with the updated list.

Comment: why not bind the list itself

Comment: And can you show us how the list is used inside of `app-component-test`?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing through the service, instead try passing through the list on it's own.

```
@Input() list: number[];
```

```
<app-component-test [list]="dataSource.list"></app-component-test>
```

Even better, if your list comes from an Observable, you can just pass the observable through with the `async` pipe:

```
@Input() list: number[];
```

```
<app-component-test [list]="list$ | async"></app-component-test>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between

1. Send in the list rather than the service.
2. Inject the service in the app-component-test constructor and get the list inside the app-component-test component instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is already some similar questions on this.

You can check this answer it is about variables not service, but it is in the same principle.

[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57800860/5055668)

Bascaly you make a local equivalent of your input object and modify it as you wish.